# Resize of VirtualBox Screen?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I've recently installed the Guest Additions CD on my windows VirtualBox running Ubuntu 14.04. It was working great for a while - screen resized automatically, etc.

However, when I turned off my host computer and restarted it today, the resolution suddenly reverted back to its pre-Guest Additions CD state. However, when I try to re-install the CD, it says it is already loaded.

Does anyone know if there is another way to get the screen back to resize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found a link that solves the issue:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/451805/screen-resolution-problem-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-virtualbox

Type the following into terminal, and it should work!

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

I'm not sure how that's any different from installing the virtual CD, but hell, if it works, I'm not gonna complain.